# parsing a number into date issue

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I am getting some results from database and I am looping over it. I check every value if it is date by using `DateTime.Parse` method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime dateValue;
    string s = "107.5"; //5/1/0107
    var canConvert = DateTime.TryParse(s, out dateValue);
    var val = canConvert ? dateValue.ToString("d") : s;
    if (canConvert)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(val);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Problem is if I am passing a value "107.5", system is considering it as a valid date and returns 5/1/0107. I am sure there must be some valid logic behind it. What is that logic? Also how can I tell compiler to ignore converting any value into which contains a `.`. Obviously I can check if the value contains a `.` and if it does, I can ignore conversion. But I don't want to go that way. I am not sure in what format the date will be returned but it will not contain a `.`

Comment: [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) is what you need.

Comment: Do you *really* not know what format at all the date will be in? If you had a few different valid formats then you could test for each one using @ShadowWizard suggestion - which is about the best answer you're likely to get.

Comment: @Jamiec fair point. Will post another idea as a new answer..

Answer (score 2):

About your only option is to decide what formats are valid, and try each one in sequence until either there is a valid parse, or you run out of valid formats.

```
var validFormats = new[]{"dd/MM/yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd"};
var dateStrings = new[]{ "13/10/2012","2000-01-01","107.2"};

DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
foreach(var d in dateStrings)
{
     if(DateTime.TryParseExact(d, validFormats, 
               CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is not valid",d);
    }
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/IXZIG43823

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format or possible formats, you can use the [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms131044.aspx) method.

However if you don't know the possible format, another way around this problem is "sanity check" for the date:

```
var canConvert = DateTime.TryParse(s, out dateValue);
if (canConvert && (dateValue.Year < 1900 || dateValue.Year > 2100))
    canConvert = false;
```

This will manually "flag" invalid dates, you can change the years range of course.

Comment: @LolCoder DateTime.TryParse also does not throw exception.

Comment: Nope, I'm talking about  DateTime.ParseExact which u have stated in first line of your answer